# Next screen on click of UITableCellView?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have created UITableCellView in flipsideViewController of my Utility template. How to show next screen onclick of UITableCellView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create files for the view (YourViewController.h, YourViewController.m, YourViewController.xib). Set class of YourViewController.xib to YourViewController in interface builder. Connect view to view in interface builder, then in code

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIViewController *controller;
    controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];

}
```